# R data.table: what is the fastest way to intersect a data.table by multiple columns by keys and groups

Tags: r, merge, data.table

**MAJOR EDIT to clarify as answers are wrong**

I have a data.table with group columns (split_by), key columns (key_by) and trait ids columns (intersect_by)

I want in each group of split_by, keep only the rows where the trait ids are shared by all the present keys in the group.

For example:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:6, key1 = 1, key2 = c(1:2, 2), group_id1= 1, group_id2= c(1:2, 2:1, 1:2), trait_id1 = 1, trait_id2 = 2:1)
setkey(dt, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)
dt
   id key1 key2 group_id1 group_id2 trait_id1 trait_id2
1:  4    1    1         1         1         1         1
2:  1    1    1         1         1         1         2
3:  5    1    2         1         1         1         2
4:  2    1    2         1         2         1         1
5:  6    1    2         1         2         1         1
6:  3    1    2         1         2         1         2

res <- intersect_this_by(dt,
                         key_by = c("key1"),
                         split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                         intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
```

I want res to be like this:

```
> res[]
   id key1 key2 group_id1 group_id2 trait_id1 trait_id2
1:  1    1    1         1         1         1         2
2:  5    1    2         1         1         1         2
3:  2    1    2         1         2         1         1
4:  6    1    2         1         2         1         1
5:  3    1    2         1         2         1         2
```

We see id 4 has been dropped as in group_id1 = 1 and group_id2 = 1 combination group (the group which id 4 belongs) there is only one combination of keys (1,1) which has these traits (1,1) whereas there are two keys combinations in this group: (1,1) and (1,2) so the traits (1,1) are not shared by all keys in this group so we drop this trait from this group, hence drop id 4. On the contrary, id 1 and 5 have same traits but different keys and they represent all the keys ( (1,1) and (1,2)) in this group so traits of id 1 and 5 are kept.

A function to achieve this is given there:

```
intersect_this_by2 <- function(dt,
                               key_by = NULL,
                               split_by = NULL,
                               intersect_by = NULL){

    dtc <- as.data.table(dt)       

    # compute number of keys in the group
    dtc[, n_keys := uniqueN(.SD), by = split_by, .SDcols = key_by]
    # compute number of keys represented by each trait in each group 
    # and keep row only if they represent all keys from the group
    dtc[, keep := n_keys == uniqueN(.SD), by = c(intersect_by, split_by), .SDcols = key_by]
    dtc <- dtc[keep == TRUE][, c("n_keys", "keep") := NULL]
    return(dtc)      
}
```

But it gets quite slow for big datasets or complex traits/keys/groups...
 the real data.table has got 10 millions rows and the traits have 30 levels...
Is there any way to improve it? Any obvious pitfalls?
Thanks for the help

**FINAL EDIT:** Uwe proposed a concise solution which is 40% faster than my initial code (which I deleted here because it was confusing)
The final function looks like this:

```
intersect_this_by_uwe <- function(dt,
                                  key_by = c("key1"),
                                  split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                                  intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2")){
    dti <- copy(dt)
    dti[, original_order_id__ := 1:.N]
    setkeyv(dti, c(split_by, intersect_by, key_by))
    uni <- unique(dti, by = c(split_by, intersect_by, key_by))
    unique_keys_by_group <-
        unique(uni, by = c(split_by, key_by))[, .N, by = c(split_by)]
    unique_keys_by_group_and_trait <-
        uni[, .N, by = c(split_by, intersect_by)]
    # 1st join to pick group/traits combinations with equal number of unique keys
    selected_groups_and_traits <-
        unique_keys_by_group_and_trait[unique_keys_by_group,
                                       on = c(split_by, "N"), nomatch = 0L]
    # 2nd join to pick records of valid subsets
    dti[selected_groups_and_traits, on = c(split_by, intersect_by)][
        order(original_order_id__), -c("original_order_id__","N")]
}
```

And for the records the benchmarks on the 10M rows dataset:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(old_way = {res <- intersect_this_by(dt,
+                                                                    key_by = c("key1"),
+                                                                    split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
+                                                                    intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))},
+                                new_way = {res <- intersect_this_by2(dt,
+                                                                     key_by = c("key1"),
+                                                                     split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
+                                                                     intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))},
+                                new_way_uwe = {res <- intersect_this_by_uwe(dt,
+                                                                            key_by = c("key1"),
+                                                                            split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
+                                                                            intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))},
+                                times = 10)
Unit: seconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
     old_way  3.145468  3.530898  3.514020  3.544661  3.577814  3.623707    10  b 
     new_way 15.670487 15.792249 15.948385 15.988003 16.097436 16.206044    10   c
 new_way_uwe  1.982503  2.350001  2.320591  2.394206  2.412751  2.436381    10 a
```

Comment: does trait order matter, can it be 3,2 and 2,3 to satisfy? or is it directional

Comment: Yes order matters

Comment: why is 4 missing from res? it is group = (2,1) with trait = (2, 1) just like id=40. if its a typo, then maybe `dt[id %in% dt[, .SD[, if (.N > 1) id, by=.(trait_id1, trait_id2)], by=.(group_id1, group_id2)]$V1]`

Comment: If order matters I'd be looking to paste the columns together and then group by that within the grouping id's. Then filter for frequency greater than 1.

Comment: 4 is missing as well because it s traits 2-1 with key 2 but there is no key 1 with same traits in same group. Sorry I think you missed the key idea but my explanations are bad I must admit!

Comment: Your approach could work if instead of n> 1 you would check that all the key columns combinations are represented.

Comment: @BenoitLondon Your descriptions are still unclear. Lets look at where Id is `4` for example. The traits are 2, 1 and its key is 2. But look at where Id is `40`, it is identical except for Id. I think you need to try and reword it  very very clearly or give more examples.

Comment: ok for the group of id 4, keys 1 and 2 are present so i need to keep all the traits combination that have keys 1 and 2 represented but id 4 has traits 2-1 and key 2 but rows with traits 2-1 in the same group have not key 1 so the set of keys is not full so traits of id 4 are rejected. I think my other answer is a better way to understand it.

Comment: @BenoitLondon That really didn't help explain at all and only made it more confusing personally. I think you need to take a step back and come up with some clearer examples, I'm not going to sink anymore time into this currently. Maybe put some context as to what and why you are trying to achieve.  Break two or three examples down into their simplest steps and write down rules separately and clearly - currently they are not.

Comment: Did you see my answer below? I think it explains much better I want to keep the traits which have all the keys represented and that in each group. id 3 and 4 have only one key represented with the same traits in their group so have to be excluded as there are two keys in their respective group

Comment: @BenoitLondon I did, but its just a dump of code - I'm not wasting my time trying to infer how you have done something. Especially the huge function at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [additional explanations by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594692/r-data-table-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-intersect-a-data-table-by-multiple-colu/50618856?noredirect=1#comment88251902_50618856), I believe to have gained a better understanding of the problem.

The OP wants to remove incomplete subsets from his dataset. Each `group_id1`, `group_id2` group contains a set of unique `key1` values. A complete subset contains at least one `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, `trait_id2`, `key1` record for *each* of the `key1` values in the `group_id1`, `group_id2` group.

It is *not* necessary to check the `key1` *values* when comparing the grouping on the `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, `trait_id2` level with the `group_id1`, `group_id2` level. It is sufficient to check if the number of distinct `key1` values is equal.

So, the solution below follows the general outline of [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50601189/3817004) but uses two joins to achieve the result:

```
setkey(dt, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
uni <- unique(dt, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))
unique_keys_by_group <- 
  unique(uni, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "key1"))[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2)]
unique_keys_by_group_and_trait <- 
  uni[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)]
# 1st join to pick group/traits combinations with equal number of unique keys
selected_groups_and_traits <- 
  unique_keys_by_group_and_trait[unique_keys_by_group, 
                                 on = .(group_id1, group_id2, N), nomatch = 0L]
# 2nd join to pick records of valid subsets
res <- dt[selected_groups_and_traits, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
  order(id), -"N"]
```

It can be verified that the result is identical to OP's result:

```
identical(
  intersect_this_by(dt,
                    key_by = c("key1"),
                    split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                    intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2")),
  res)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Note that the `uniqueN()` function is *not* used due to performance issues as shown in [the benchmarks of my first (wrong) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50618856/3817004).

#### Benchmark comparison

OP's benchmark data is used (10 M rows).

```
library(microbenchmark)
mb <- microbenchmark(
  old_way = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    res <- intersect_this_by(DT,
                             key_by = c("key1"),
                             split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                             intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
  },
  uwe = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    setkey(DT, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
    uni <- 
      unique(DT, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))
    unique_keys_by_group <- 
      unique(uni, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "key1"))[
        , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2)]
    unique_keys_by_group_and_trait <- 
      uni[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)]
    selected_groups_and_traits <- 
      unique_keys_by_group_and_trait[unique_keys_by_group, 
                                     on = .(group_id1, group_id2, N), nomatch = 0L]
    res <- DT[selected_groups_and_traits, 
              on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id), -"N"]
  },
  times = 3L)
mb
```

The solution presented here is 40% faster:

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
>  old_way 7.251277 7.315796 7.350636 7.380316 7.400315 7.420315     3   b
>      uwe 4.379781 4.461368 4.546267 4.542955 4.629510 4.716065     3  a
> ```

---

#### Edit: Further performance improvements

The [Op has asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594692/r-data-table-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-intersect-a-data-table-by-multiple-colu/50624794#comment88265785_50624794) for ideas to further improve performance.

I already have tried different approaches including a double nested grouping (using slow `uniqueN()` just for simplified display of code):

```
res <- DT[, {
  nuk_g = uniqueN(key1) 
  .SD[, if(nuk_g == uniqueN(key1)) .SD, by = .(trait_id1, trait_id2)]
}, by = .(group_id1, group_id2)][order(id)]
```

but they were all slower for the *given benchmark data*.

It is likely that perfomance of a particular method does not depend solely on the *problem size*, ie., the number of rows, but also on the *problem structure* e.g., the number of different groups, treats, and keys as as well as on data types, etc.

So, without knowing the structure of your production data and the context of your computational flow I do not think it is worthwhile to spent more time on benchmarking.

Anyway, there is one suggestion: Make sure that `setkey()` is called only once as it is rather costly (about 2 seconds) but speeds-up all subsequent operations. (Verify with `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`).

Comment: Thank you very much! it is simpler and faster than my first version.
On my real dataset I got 34% speed up and results match.
Merging on the N's was genius!
May I ask you any idea to speed it up even more? :D

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you know if the order of the keys matter? (like biggest number of groups first or lowest?)

Comment: This might be the case, but my experience with `setkey()` is limited, so I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

Although the answer below does reproduce the expected result for the small sample dataset it *fails to give the correct answer* for the large, 10 M rows dataset provided by the OP.

However, I have decided to keep this wrong answer because of the benchmark results which show the poor performance of the `uniqueN()` function. In addition, the answer contains benchmarks of much faster, alternative solutions.

---

---

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to keep only those rows where the unique combinations of `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, and `trait_id2`appear in more than one distinct `key1`.

This can be achieved by counting the unique values of `key1` in each group of `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, and `trait_id2` and by selecting only those combinations of `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, and `trait_id2` where the count is larger than one. Finally, the matching rows are retrieved by joining:

```
library(data.table)
sel <- dt[, uniqueN(key1), by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][V1 > 1]
sel
```

> ```
>    group_id1 group_id2 trait_id1 trait_id2 V1
> 1:         1         2         3         1  2
> 2:         2         2         2         1  2
> 3:         2         1         1         2  2
> 4:         1         1         1         1  2
> 5:         1         1         2         2  2
> 6:         2         2         2         2  2
> 7:         1         1         1         2  2
> 8:         1         1         3         2  2
> ```

```
res <- dt[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][order(id), -"V1"]
res
```

> ```
>     id key1 group_id1 trait_id1 group_id2 trait_id2 extra
>  1:  1    2         1         3         2         1     u
>  2:  2    1         2         2         2         1     g
>  3:  5    2         2         1         1         2     g
>  4:  8    2         1         3         2         1     o
>  5:  9    2         1         1         1         1     d
>  6: 10    2         2         1         1         2     g
>  7: 13    1         2         1         1         2     c
>  8: 14    2         1         2         1         2     t
>  9: 15    1         1         3         2         1     y
> 10: 16    2         1         3         2         1     v
> 11: 19    2         2         2         2         2     y
> 12: 22    2         2         2         2         1     g
> 13: 24    2         1         1         1         2     i
> 14: 25    1         1         3         1         2     n
> 15: 26    1         2         2         2         2     y
> 16: 27    1         1         1         1         1     n
> 17: 28    1         1         1         1         2     h
> 18: 29    1         2         2         2         2     b
> 19: 30    2         1         3         1         2     k
> 20: 31    1         2         2         2         2     w
> 21: 35    1         1         2         1         2     q
> 22: 37    2         2         1         1         2     r
> 23: 39    1         1         1         1         2     o
>     id key1 group_id1 trait_id1 group_id2 trait_id2 extra
> ```

This reproduces OP's expected result but is it also the *fastest way* as requested by the OP?

---

#### Benchmarking Part 1

[OP's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50601189/3817004) to create benchmark data (but with 1 M rows instead of 10 M rows) is used here:

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 1e6
p <- 1e5
m <- 5
dt <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                 key1 = sample(1:m, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 group_id1 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 trait_id1 = sample(1:p, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 group_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 trait_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 extra = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE))
```

I was quite surprised to find that the solution using `uniqueN()` is not the fastest one:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>  old_way  489.4606  496.3801  523.3361  503.2997  540.2739  577.2482     3 a  
>  new_way 9356.4131 9444.5698 9567.4035 9532.7265 9672.8987 9813.0710     3   c
>     uwe1 5946.4533 5996.7388 6016.8266 6047.0243 6052.0133 6057.0023     3  b
> ```

Benchmark code:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  old_way = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    res <- intersect_this_by(DT,
                             key_by = c("key1"),
                             split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                             intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
  },
  new_way = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    res <- intersect_this_by2(DT,
                              key_by = c("key1"),
                              split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                              intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
  },
  uwe1 = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    sel <- DT[, uniqueN(key1), by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][V1 > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  times = 3L)
```

Note that for each run a fresh copy of the benchmark data is used in order to avoid any side effects from previous runs, e.g., indices set by `data.table`.

Switching verbose mode on

```
options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)
```

reveals that most of the time is spent in computing `uniqueN()` for all the groups:

> ```
> sel <- DT[, uniqueN(key1), by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][V1 > 1]
>
> Detected that j uses these columns: key1 
> Finding groups using forderv ... 0.060sec 
> Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000sec 
> Getting back original order ... 0.050sec 
> lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'uniqueN(key1)'
> GForce is on, left j unchanged
> Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
> Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
>   collecting discontiguous groups took 0.084s for 570942 groups
>   eval(j) took 5.505s for 570942 calls
> 5.940sec
> ```

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1120). However, the alternative `lenght(unique())` (for which `uniqueN()` is an abbreviation) brings only a moderate speed-up of 2.

So I started to look for ways to avoid `uniqueN()` or `lenght(unique())`.

---

#### Benchmarking Part 2

I have found two alternatives which are sufficiently fast. Both create a data.table of unique combinations of `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, `trait_id2`, *and* `key1` in a first step, count the number of distinct `key1` values for each group of `group_id1`, `group_id2`, `trait_id1`, `trait_id2`, and filter for counts greater one:

```
sel <- DT[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)][
  , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
```

and

```
sel <- unique(DT, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))[
  , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
```

The verbose output shows that computing times for these variants are significantly better.

For benchmarking, only the fastest methods are used but now with 10 M rows. In addition, each variant is tried with `setkey()` and `setorder()`, resp.,  applied beforehand:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  old_way = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    res <- intersect_this_by(DT,
                             key_by = c("key1"),
                             split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                             intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
  },
  uwe3 = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    sel <- DT[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)][
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  uwe3k = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    setkey(DT, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
    sel <- DT[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)][
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  uwe3o = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    setorder(DT, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
    sel <- DT[, .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)][
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  uwe4 = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    sel <- unique(DT, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))[
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  uwe4k = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    setkey(DT, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
    sel <- unique(DT, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))[
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  uwe4o = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    setorder(DT, group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2, key1)
    sel <- unique(DT, by = c("group_id1", "group_id2", "trait_id1", "trait_id2", "key1"))[
      , .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][N > 1]
    res <- DT[sel, on = .(group_id1, group_id2, trait_id1, trait_id2)][
      order(id)]
  },
  times = 3L)
```

The benchmark results for the 10 M case show that both variants are faster than OP's `intersect_this_by()` function and that keying and ordering is pushing speed-up (with a minimal advantage for ordering).

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
>  old_way 7.173517 7.198064 7.256211 7.222612 7.297559 7.372506     3    d
>     uwe3 6.820324 6.833151 6.878777 6.845978 6.908003 6.970029     3   c 
>    uwe3k 5.349949 5.412018 5.436806 5.474086 5.480234 5.486381     3 a   
>    uwe3o 5.423440 5.432562 5.467376 5.441683 5.489344 5.537006     3 a   
>     uwe4 6.270724 6.276757 6.301774 6.282790 6.317299 6.351807     3  b  
>    uwe4k 5.280763 5.295251 5.418803 5.309739 5.487823 5.665906     3 a   
>    uwe4o 4.921627 5.095762 5.157010 5.269898 5.274702 5.279506     3 a
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is still not the correct answer. The criterion is that all keys form the group should be represented by that trait combination for the trait-group combiantion to be kept. see my answer below as I think it is much clearer.
We want to keep rows where uniqueN(keys) in group-traits grouping is the same as uniqueN(keys) in the group_id grouping.

Comment: I added the expected number of rows in the 10M case so you can check

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a `tidyverse` approach and show the equivalent in `data.table`.

Let me know if this result isn't whats intended because it does differ from your required output - but its what you've described in text.

#### 1. Tidy approach

Just creating a single column from the traits and then grouping by the grouping columns and the new combined traits. Filter for group frequency greater than 1.

```
dt %>%
  mutate(comb = paste0(trait_id1, trait_id2)) %>%
  group_by(group_id1, group_id2, comb) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```

#### 2. data.table approach

Much the same methodology as the prior tidy approach just written in `data.table`.

Using answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233309/fast-concatenation-of-data-table-columns) to find fast paste methods.

```
dt[, comb := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "")), .SDcols = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2")][, freq := .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, comb)][freq > 1]
```

### Comparison

Comparing the two methods, and Chinsoons comment the speeds are:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(zac_tidy = {
  dt %>%
    mutate(comb = paste0(trait_id1, trait_id2)) %>%
    group_by(group_id1, group_id2, comb) %>%
    filter(n() > 1)
},
zac_dt = {
  dt[, comb := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "")), .SDcols = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2")][, freq := .N, by = .(group_id1, group_id2, comb)][freq > 1]
},
chin_dt = {
  dt[id %in% dt[, .SD[, if (.N > 1) id, by=.(trait_id1, trait_id2)], by=.(group_id1, group_id2)]$V1]
}, times = 100)
```

---

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 zac_tidy 4.151115 4.677328 6.150869 5.552710 7.765968  8.886388   100
   zac_dt 1.965013 2.201499 2.829999 2.640686 3.507516  3.831240   100
  chin_dt 4.567210 5.217439 6.972013 7.330628 8.233379 12.807005   100

> identical(zac_dt, chin_dt)
[1] TRUE
```

---

#### Comparison at 10 million

10 repeats:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
 zac_tidy 12.492261 14.169898 15.658218 14.680287 16.31024 22.062874    10
   zac_dt 10.169312 10.967292 12.425121 11.402416 12.23311 21.036535    10
  chin_dt  6.381693  6.793939  8.449424  8.033886  9.78187 12.005604    10
 chin_dt2  5.536246  6.888020  7.914103  8.310142  8.74655  9.600121    10
```

I'd therefore be recommending Chinsoon's method. Either works.

Comment: maybe time with 10mil rows since thats OP dimensions. can make chin_dt faster using `dt2[, .SD[, if (.N > 1) .SD, by=.(trait_id1, trait_id2)], by=.(group_id1, group_id2)]`

Comment: You do not use the key?

Comment: Maybe we can forget the group to start and work in a single group defined by some values of group_id columns?

Comment: @BenoitLondon Well given that you didn't fully explain this doesn't surprise me. Let me have another look.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: also paste is not safe as if you have 11,2 and 1,12 it gives the same when pasting so I d rather avoid any pasting method...

Answer (score 1):

Other answer does not solve the problem but I have found some method inspired by it. First compute the number of keys present in the group and for each trait combination keep only the one with the full number of keys

```
 intersect_this_by2 <- function(dt,
         key_by = NULL,
         split_by = NULL,
         intersect_by = NULL){

    if (is.null(intersect_by) |
        is.null(key_by) |
        !is.data.frame(dt) |
        nrow(dt) == 0) {
        return(dt)
    }
    data_table_input <- is.data.table(dt)
    dtc <- as.data.table(dt)

    if (!is.null(split_by)) {
        # compute number of keys in the group
        dtc[, n_keys := uniqueN(.SD), by = split_by, .SDcols = key_by]
        # compute number of keys represented by each trait in each group 
        # and keep row only if they represent all keys from the group
        dtc[, keep := n_keys == uniqueN(.SD), by = c(intersect_by, split_by), .SDcols = key_by]
        dtc <- dtc[keep == TRUE][, c("n_keys", "keep") := NULL]
    } else {
        dtc[, n_keys := uniqueN(.SD), .SDcols = key_by]
        dtc[, keep := n_keys == uniqueN(.SD), by = c(intersect_by), .SDcols = key_by]
        dtc <- dtc[keep == TRUE][, c("n_keys", "keep") := NULL]
    }
    if (!data_table_input) {
        return(as.data.frame(dtc))
    } else {
        return(dtc)
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is much slower on my real dataset (5-6 times slower) but I think this function helps to understand the problem better,. also a dataset closer to my real one is defined below:

```
pacman::p_load(data.table, microbenchmark, testthat)

set.seed(0)
n <- 1e7
p <- 1e5
m <- 5
dt <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                 key1 = sample(1:m, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 group_id1 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 trait_id1 = sample(1:p, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 group_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 trait_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 extra = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(old_way = {res <- intersect_this_by(dt,
                                                                    key_by = c("key1"),
                                                                    split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                                                                    intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))},
                               new_way = {res <- intersect_this_by2(dt,
                                                                   key_by = c("key1"),
                                                                   split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                                                                   intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))},
                               times = 1)


Unit: seconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 old_way  5.891489  5.891489  5.891489  5.891489  5.891489  5.891489     1
 new_way 18.455860 18.455860 18.455860 18.455860 18.455860 18.455860     1
```

For info the number of rows of res in this example  is

```
> set.seed(0)
> n <- 1e7
> p <- 1e5
> m <- 5
> dt <- data.table(id = 1:n,
                   key1 = sample(1:m, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   group_id1 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   trait_id1 = sample(1:p, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   group_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   trait_id2 = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                   extra = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE))
> res <- intersect_this_by(dt,
                            key_by = c("key1"),
                            split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                            intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
> nrow(res)
[1] 7099860
> res <- intersect_this_by2(dt,
                            key_by = c("key1"),
                            split_by = c("group_id1", "group_id2"),
                            intersect_by = c("trait_id1", "trait_id2"))
> nrow(res)
[1] 7099860
```

Comment: the slow part appears to be in the second uniqueN where actually we just need to check that n_keys <= uniqueN(.SD) we dont need to explore the whole of .SD so we just need to be sure every key present in the group is also present for this traits combination. maybe something that keeps the group keys and checks with %in% would be faster...