# Intersection of items between groups in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, intersection

I have a `data.table` with two columns, one with a `groupID` and the other with a `color`. I want to find the length of the intersections or a pairwise intersection operation between all groups. There are similar posts online but nothing exactly as far as what I am looking for.

```
require(data.table)


set.seed(1)
x <- data.table(
  groupID = paste0(sample(LETTERS), sample(LETTERS, replace = TRUE)),
  color = sapply(1:length(LETTERS), function(x) sample(colors()[1:10])[1:sample(5:10)[1]])
)

x <- x[, .(color = unlist(color)), keyby = groupID]
```

The table below doesn't have correct values but it would look something like this:

```
groups <- x[, .N, keyby = groupID][,groupID]; results <- CJ(groups, groups)
results[, intersectionLength := sapply(1:nrow(results), function(x) sample(5:10)[1])]
```

**EDIT**

[This post has a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594692/r-data-table-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-intersect-a-data-table-by-multiple-colu) How could I apply this to my problem?

Comment: The `results` have both columns with same name 'groups'

Comment: Yes, this is true. Thought it wouldn't matter, but also am trying to point out they are they same columns basically. @akrun

Comment: If it is a smaller example and have an expected output, it would be more easier to understand.  You seem to `sample`

Comment: The `sample` is to control the example data. As for an expected output, I am trying to find a solution so I am not sure how to create that. The `results` object is what it will look like, just doesn't have the correct values. @akrun

Comment: I will update the post with a smaller example. @akrun

Comment: Do you need `CJ(group1 = unique(x$groupID), group2 = unique(x$groupID))[,  .(group1,  group2, intersectionLength = unlist(Map(function(u, v) length(intersect(x$color[x$groupID == u], x$color[x$groupID == v])), group1, group2)))]`

Comment: I think this might be it, yes. What does `Map` do in this case? @akrun

Comment: It goes through corresponding elements of 'group1' and 'group2', extract the 'color' based on `==` with 'groupID' and gett the length of intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one optioin with `Map` to compare the pairwise elements of group columns to extract the `intersect`ing 'color' values and get the `length` of it

```
library(data.table)
CJ(group1 = unique(x$groupID), group2 = unique(x$groupID))[,
   .(group1, group2, intersectionLength = unlist(Map(function(u, v) 
   length(intersect(x$color[x$groupID == u], 
      x$color[x$groupID == v])), group1, group2)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option to remove dupes in cases where groups are flipped:

```
ans <- x[x, on=.(color), allow.cartesian=TRUE][groupID!=i.groupID, 
    .(intersectionLength=uniqueN(color)), 
    .(g1=pmin(groupID, i.groupID), g2=pmax(groupID, i.groupID))]
```

output:

```
     g1 g2 intersectionLength
  1: AT AT                  6
  2: AT CZ                  3
  3: AT DO                  6
  4: AT EW                  5
  5: AT FT                  4
 ---                         
347: XL YL                  3
348: XL ZF                  6
349: YL YL                  5
350: YL ZF                  3
351: ZF ZF                  7
```

Comment: Also an excellent approach, takes care of the cleaning aspects during processing. Next step might be to remove `AT` and `AT` columns for example. I have seen `pmin` and `pmax` used before but never often enough to stop and understand what they do. Can you explain how they work in this solution @chinsoon12?

Comment: Pmin and pmax can be used to sort each row of a 2 columns data.frame

Comment: Do you mind providing the solution if I needed the `union` as opposed to `intersection`? @chinsoon12

Comment: What do you mean by union? Can you show an example?